# Help with flu symptoms vs. help against flu symptoms

Tags: word-usage

Would you please explain which is better when talking about medicinal problems?

Eg. in the sentence:

> Vitamin C *helps with* flu symptoms.
>
> or
>
> Vitamin C *helps against* flu symptoms.

Our teacher asked us to translate a similar sentence (*Vitamin C helps against/with the following problems* - my translation) and I tried to google both terms but was not able to tell the difference.

Thank you.

Comment: **Vitamin C helps cure flu symptoms.**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I need to know which preposition is better when used without the verb "cure" and if there is a difference.

Comment: "helps *fighting* flu symptoms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**with**" is definitely the most common preposition ([**Google search**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22helps%20with%20flu%22&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GKLB_ruRU733RU733&ei=E8PcWc_kPIfE6QTc1p_QBQ&start=20&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662)). However, if you use "**against**" you won't be wrong either ([**Google search**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22helps%20against%20flu%22&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GKLB_ruRU733RU733&ei=msPcWeLONOXB6ASJjo_4Cg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662)).